# Javascript 2D Array Not Returning Results as Expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays declared as the following:

```
var rangeValues = [[0.001, 0.01], [0.0000001, 0.000001]];
```

This array is used to fill the values of a drop down, since I essentially need a tuple for each drop down item's value.  I proceed to access the values of the drop down with the following:

```
rangeTuple = document.getElementById('rangeSelection').value;
console.log(rangeTuple);

selectedMinRange = rangeTuple[0];
selectedMaxRange = rangeTuple[1];
console.log(selectedMinRange +  " | " +  selectedMaxRange[1]);
```

And I receive the following output:

```
0.001,0.01
0 | .
```

In my understanding (albeit limited with JS :) ), `rangeTuple` should be an array with two items in it.  When `rangeTuple` is logged, it looks correct.  However, when I try and assign the items in this tuple to a pair global variables, the values are not the ones I expect.

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: What values are you expecting? What values do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of an input is always a string.  You will need to split that string to use it in the way you want:

```
rangeTuple = document.getElementById('rangeSelection').value;
console.log(rangeTuple);

// split it
rangeTuple = rangeTuple.split(",");

selectedMinRange = rangeTuple[0];
selectedMaxRange = rangeTuple[1];
console.log(selectedMinRange +  " | " +  selectedMaxRange);
```

Comment: +1. Yeah, the DOM doesn't "hold" a JavaScript object for you as the original object.